# Why Javascript code that use jQuery sometimes doesn't listen for events in an Angular2 application?

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, angular

Time ago we purchased this [template](https://themeforest.net/item/materialize-material-design-admin-template/11446068) and we have used it in an **angularJS** application without any problem.
Now for another project we have switch to `Angular 2` and we want use the same theme but we got this weird behaviour: sometimes works as expected but most of the times isn't working.
We have inspected the code using the firefox console and this is the result when is working:
[image]
And this is the output console when is not working:
[image]
For an (mine) unknown reason sometimes `materialize.min.js` is not listening for events.
Unfortunately due to  copyright issue I can't post the `materialize.min.js` source code but I can post mine:
**index.html**

```
<html>
  <head>
    <base href="/">
    <title>Angular QuickStart</title>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <!-- 1. Load libraries -->
     <!-- Polyfill(s) for older browsers -->
    <script src="node_modules/core-js/client/shim.min.js"></script>
    <script src="node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone.js"></script>
    <script src="node_modules/reflect-metadata/Reflect.js"></script>
    <script src="node_modules/systemjs/dist/system.src.js"></script>
    <!-- 2. Configure SystemJS -->
    <script src="systemjs.config.js"></script>
    <script>
      System.import('app').catch(function(err){ console.error(err); });
    </script>


      <link href="css/materialize.min.css" type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" media="screen,projection">
      <link href="css/style.min.css" type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" media="screen,projection">
      <link href="css/layouts/style-fullscreen.css" type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" media="screen,projection">
  </head>
  <!-- 3. Display the application -->
  <body>
    <my-app>Loading...</my-app>
    <!--materialize js-->  
   <script
              src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.1.1.min.js"
              integrity="sha256-hVVnYaiADRTO2PzUGmuLJr8BLUSjGIZsDYGmIJLv2b8="
              crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/materialize.min.js"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

**app.component.ts**

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  template: `
      <header-navbar></header-navbar> 
          <div id="main">
            <!-- START WRAPPER -->
            <div class="wrapper">
              <navbar></navbar>
              <section id="content">
                <div class="container">
                  <router-outlet></router-outlet>
                </div>
              </section>
            </div>
          </div>
      `
})
export class AppComponent { }
```

**EDIT**
Even if I use a local copy of jQuery is not working properly.

Answer (score 1):

Provided your materialize.min.js relies on jQuery, I would suspect the reason it works sometimes and not others is that your CDN link is not always loading correctly. I might suggest downloading a copy of jQuery and loading it from a local source that you control.

Edit: When you say "not working" when loaded from a local source, do you mean it is still working sometimes but not consistently? Or do you mean not working at all?

Comment: Still working sometimes, in the next days I'll try to use the server side rendering to see if there is an improvment